# How do add word wrap in a ionic-selectable?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the ionic-selectable plugin in my ionic App.  Occasionally I get longer text in my section areas that get cut off and are followed by ...  .

[image: view of ionic item]

I have been able to add the css from the ionic-selectable plugin to my global.scss

```
@import '~ionic-selectable/esm5/ionic-selectable.component.min.css';

.ionic-selectable-item-is-selected,.ionic-selectable-item-is-disabled {
  color:#ff0000 !important;
}

.ionic-selectable-value {
  overflow-wrap: break-word; // does not work
  font-size: 10px; 
  text-size-adjust: 10%; // does not work
}


.ionic-selectable-item {
  overflow-wrap: break-word; // does not work
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label  position="stacked" class="ion-text-wrap" >{{ 'NEW.dept' | translate }}</ion-label>
  <ionic-selectable
    placeholder="{{ 'NEW.selectdept' | translate }}"
    name="business"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedBusiness"
    [items]="list"
    itemValueField="name"
    itemTextField="name"
    [canSearch]="true">
  </ionic-selectable>
</ion-item>
```

link to plugin

https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable

I have been able to edit font size, colors etc..  But I cannot add a word wrap or auto text size to fit in div.ionic-selectable-value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This no longer works

```
ion-label {
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

The updated answer is

```
.item.sc-ion-label-md-h, .item .sc-ion-label-md-h{
  white-space: normal !important;
 }

.item.sc-ion-label-ios-h, .item .sc-ion-label-ios-h{
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

this turns of the white-space: nowrap which was the real culprit

Comment: Just a small notice, I think you could wrap it up like this:

`.item .sc-ion-label-md-h, .item .sc-ion-label-ios-h{
    white-space: normal !important;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ng-deep which will pierce the shadow DOM.

```
 ::ng-deep .ionic-selectable-item {
   overflow-wrap: break-word!important;
   min-height: 20px;
   font-size: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Did not work.  Seems strange I can adjust the font-size or color but cannot get overflow-wrap to work even when increase the size of the container

Comment: can you post the related HTML or otherwise create a sample somewhere?

Comment: I just posted the html and link to plugin

Comment: Have you tried connecting your ios or android device to a remote debugger and seeing if you can fiddle around with CSS to see what works?

Comment: You can probably even do this from the demo located at https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-basic?file=pages/home/home.html. It looks like it creates a bunch of extra DOM elements. You'll probably need to inspect and find the appropriate level.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ng-template inside ionic-selectable. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-item-template?file=app%2Fpages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) is the example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).